# Set the output of a function equal to a variable

Tags: php, css, function

How would i set the output of a custom php function to a variable?

The function is:

```
function getRandomColor1() {
global $cols;
$num_cols = count($cols);
$rand = array_rand($cols);
$rand_col = $cols[$rand];
echo $rand_col;
unset($cols[$rand]);
}
```

How would i set getRandomColor1 equal to $RandomColor1?

I need it to be a variable so I can use it in css like:

```
#boxone1 {  
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
background: <?=$RandomColor1?>; 
float: left;
}
```

If its not possible to set it as a variable, how else could i put the output of the function into css?

Comment: @truth, where would i put return and what would the syntax of that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, there are a number of answers that are pointing in the right direction, but to spell things out for you:

Your function needs to [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) the value that you want. Please read this link, since it is the answer to your question (thanks to egasimus for the link).

So something like this:

```
function getRandomColor1() {
    global $cols;
    $num_cols = count($cols);
    $rand = array_rand($cols);
    $rand_col = $cols[$rand];
    unset($cols[$rand]);
    return $rand_col;
}
```

And then

```
#boxone1 {  
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: <?php echo getRandomColor1(); ?>; 
    float: left;
}
```

Also, `<?=` can lead to bugs and security issues if the server you're working with doesn't have the proper setting enabled (or decides to disable it later). It's probably safer to just always use `<?php echo`.

Comment: Thank you for putting it together! i was just about to figure it out myself haha! thanks

Answer (score 3):

You `return` the value at the end of your function (e.g.: `return $rand_col`). See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) for the docs.

Comment: I tried, background: <?php echo $rand_col; ?>; but i get the notice that $rand_col is undefined variable

Comment: Where would i add in the return?

Answer (score 1):

If the css and the php are on the same file, you could do:

```
background: <?=getRandomColor1();?>;
```

Comment: i tried this earlier but i get undefined index on line 33 (which is the line: $rand_col = $cols[$rand];      )

Answer (score 1):

```css
#boxone1 {  
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: <?php echo $yourVariable; ?>; 
    float: left;
}
```

See [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) for more info.

Comment: im asking how i set the function to a variable. I know how to put a variable in the css as it shows that in my example

Comment: @ryno set a return for your function and use `<?php echo yourFunction(); ?>`

Comment: i still am getting an undefined index on line 33 (which is the line: $rand_col = $cols[$rand]; )

Comment: `$cols` is not defined as array. And use `return $rand_col` instead of `echo $rand_col` in order to make your function working for CSS.